# Given a list of vertices in a binary tree output minimal sublist with the same lowest common ancestor

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity

The input: a binary tree and a list $L$ of vertices in that tree.

The output: a sublist of $L$ of minimal length that has the same lowest common ancestor as $L$. If there is several sublists of minimal length it is OK to output any one of them.

We could just check all the possible sublists of $L$ but that seems inefficient.

Is there an algorithm for this problem whose running time grows polynomially with respect to the length of $L$?

One idea that doesn't work is checking for each vertex in $L$ whether removing it changes the lowest common ancestor and then simply removing the "useless" vertices. If it worked the running time would be linear.

Another idea that might work but I haven't verified in detail is to pick one vertex removing which doesn't change the lowest common ancestor, then remove it and again pick one vertex etc. This has a quadratic time.

Comment: I suggest you work through some examples until you spot the pattern.

Comment: Designing an algorithm that is bounded by $poly(|L|)$ might not be possible since finding the lowest common ancestor just for two nodes would take $\Omega(n)$ time and $n$ could be exponential in $(|L|)$. Are you sure you are looking for a $poly(|L|)$ algorithm and not for some linear/quadratic algorithm in $n$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I assume that the overall number of vertices is a fixed large number.

Comment: @cory I did not understand what you meant. By fixed, you mean $n = O(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your binary tree as a binary search tree on the integers $1$ through $n$ to find that the answer for some given list $L \subseteq [1, n]$ will be $\{\min L, \max L\}$. In case you are not given a BST, you can traverse the given tree in-order to find those values in linear time (though that might be dependent on the data structure used to store $L$).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by $\{ min L, max L\}$. How it will give a minimal list? Thanks.

Comment: By that I mean the minimal and maximal elements of $L$ according to an in-order traversal of the given tree, respectively. They are basically the "leftmost" and "rightmost" nodes in $L$.

Comment: Now, I understand your algorithm. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $v$ is the lowest common ancestor of the given list of vertices $L$. Let $T_{\ell}$ denote the subtree rooted at the left child of $v$, and $T_{r}$ denote the subtree rooted at the right child of $v$.

> **Observation**: There are two vertices $x$ and $y$ in $L$ such that $x$ belongs to $T_{\ell}$ and $y$ belongs to $T_{r}$.
>
> **Proof:** For the sake of contradiction assume that the above fact is not true. Now, without loss of generality, we can assume that there is no vertex in $L$ that belongs to $T_{r}$. In this case, the left child of $v$ can act as an ancestor of $L$. Moreover, it appears in the tree at a lower level than $v$. This contradicts that $v$ is the lowest common ancestor of $L$.

Based on the above observation, we can further say that $v$ is the lowest common ancestor of $x$ and $y$. Because if this is not the case, $x$ and $y$ would have appeared in the same subtree $T_{\ell}$ or $T_{r}$.

Now, your algorithm just needs to output these two vertices $x$ and $y$ since these vertices are the minimal vertices that have the same ancestor as $L$. This gives the following linear time algorithm for the problem.

**Algorithm:**

1. Find the lowest common ancestor of $L$ in $O(n)$ time. Suppose $v$ is this ancestor.
2. If $v \in L$, output $v$.
3. If $v \notin L$, perform a DFS in $T_{\ell}$ and $T_{r}$. Find any vertex $x \in T_{\ell}$ that belongs to $L$, and any vertex $y \in T_{r}$ that belongs to $L$. Output $x$ and $y$. This step takes $O(n)$ time.